# for loop using dates in url address

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a URL that looks like this: http://nationalbank.kz/?docid=105&cmomdate=2018-01-03&switch=english

I would like to loop over all dates staring from 2015 and store data in a data frame. I am getting an error if I run the following:

```
StartDate <- "2017-07-01"
EndDate <- "2017-07-10"
dates <- seq(as.Date(StartDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"),
             as.Date(EndDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), by='days')

ML = list()

for (date in dates) {
  url = paste0("http://nationalbank.kz/?docid=105&cmomdate=",
               as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d", origin = "1960-10-01"),
               "&switch=english")
  p <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//table[1]') %>%
    html_table(fill = T)
  dt = p[[11]]
  tdt = as.data.frame(dt)

  ML[[date]] = tdt
}

all = do.call(rbind, ML)
all
```

The error message is `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match`.

But when I run it for only 1 date, it seems to be working:

```
url <- "http://nationalbank.kz/?docid=105&cmomdate=20187-07-01&switch=english"

p <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//table[1]') %>%
  html_table(fill = T)
dt = p[[11]]
tdt = t(dt)
tdt

ML = list()

for (i in 1:3) {
  ML[[i]] = tdt
}

all = do.call(rbind, ML)
all
```

The output is:

```
   [,1]               [,2]           [,3]       [,4]               
X1 "Type of security" "NIN"          "Maturity" "Type of placement"
X2 "Notes NBK"        "KZW1KD072398" "7 day"    "Auction"          
X1 "Type of security" "NIN"          "Maturity" "Type of placement"
X2 "Notes NBK"        "KZW1KD072398" "7 day"    "Auction"          
X1 "Type of security" "NIN"          "Maturity" "Type of placement"
X2 "Notes NBK"        "KZW1KD072398" "7 day"    "Auction"          
   [,5]                [,6]              [,7]             
X1 "Date of placement" "Settlement date" "Redemption date"
X2 "09.04.2018"        "09.04.2018"      "16.04.2018"     
X1 "Date of placement" "Settlement date" "Redemption date"
X2 "09.04.2018"        "09.04.2018"      "16.04.2018"     
X1 "Date of placement" "Settlement date" "Redemption date"
X2 "09.04.2018"        "09.04.2018"      "16.04.2018"     
   [,8]                         [,9]                      
X1 "Actual amount of placement" ""                        
X2 "339 999 999 929.33 tenge"   "3 405 587 268 (quantity)"
X1 "Actual amount of placement" ""                        
X2 "339 999 999 929.33 tenge"   "3 405 587 268 (quantity)"
X1 "Actual amount of placement" ""                        
X2 "339 999 999 929.33 tenge"   "3 405 587 268 (quantity)"
   [,10]                      [,11]                     
X1 "Demand"                   ""                        
X2 "366 198 211 200.00 tenge" "3 668 000 000 (quantity)"
X1 "Demand"                   ""                        
X2 "366 198 211 200.00 tenge" "3 668 000 000 (quantity)"
X1 "Demand"                   ""                        
X2 "366 198 211 200.00 tenge" "3 668 000 000 (quantity)"
   [,12]                     [,13]           [,14]           
X1 "Weighted-averaged price" "Cut price"     "Yield (coupon)"
X2 "99.8359 tenge"           "99.8359 tenge" "8.5707 %"      
X1 "Weighted-averaged price" "Cut price"     "Yield (coupon)"
X2 "99.8359 tenge"           "99.8359 tenge" "8.5707 %"      
X1 "Weighted-averaged price" "Cut price"     "Yield (coupon)"
X2 "99.8359 tenge"           "99.8359 tenge" "8.5707 %"
```

What is wrong with my previous code?

Comment: Error messages provide valuable clues about what is going wrong. What error do you get? Do you get an error for any date range, or just the one you tried? Is it a particular day that gives an error?

Comment: Sorry, I was just editing my post to include the error message. It says `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match`

Comment: I also tested out several date ranges ... Still get the same message

Comment: And what line produces the error? I'm guessing the `rbind` line. Since the error tells you that there are different numbers of columns, have you looked at the results in `ML` to see how many columns each item has? `sapply(ML, ncol)`?

Comment: Yes, seems like `rbind` is producing the error. However, `ML` also showing `NULL` when I check it using `head(ML)[[1]]`.

Comment: Can you investigate what you do have enough to isolate the earliest problem? You know, set `date = dates[1]` and run every line in your loop, inspecting the results, if you don't find problems set `date = dates[2]` and do it again...

Comment: OK, will try that. Thank you!

Comment: `ML[[date]]` does not seem to be working here. Maybe it is getting converted to number? But I tried to add another `for` loop: `for (i in length(dates)) {
    ML[[i]] = tdt
  }`. Still the same error produced.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the issue is that the web page is returning an inconsistently formatted page, so that when you're calling p[[11]], it's not returning the consistent information and in turn throwing errors when trying to rbind differently sized data frames.  The code below highlights this issue with the inserted print() that displays the date and the variable length of the list() that is assigned to 'p'.  The date that throws things out is '2008-04-04' -- the fix below simply checks if the list length is 14, and if so, add its to ML; the do.call to rbind then concatenates these as expected.

```
library(rvest)
StartDate <- "2017-07-01"
EndDate <- "2017-07-10"
dates <- seq(as.Date(StartDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"),
             as.Date(EndDate, format="%Y-%m-%d"), by='days')

ML = list()

date <-
for (date in dates) {
  url = paste0("http://nationalbank.kz/?docid=105&cmomdate=",
               as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d", origin = "1960-10-01"),
               "&switch=english")
  p <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//table[1]') %>%
    html_table(fill = T)

  print(paste(as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d", origin = "1960-10-01"),length(p)))

  if(length(p) == 14) {
  dt = p[[11]]
  tdt = as.data.frame(dt)

  ML[[date]] = tdt
  }
}

all = do.call(rbind, ML)
all
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Since both `StartDate` and `endDate` are in 2017, how are you generating values for 2008?

Comment: This is a good question :)  In brief, I just copied the example script...In looking it over, I note that the origin date that's specified is "1960-10-01" perhaps this is the issue here and also the root of the other issue?

Comment: Also, you may want to check out the library(lubridate) -- it's a nice collection of date functions that might help here.   Generally, origin is '1970-01-01'  but do also note this cannot always be relied on in all environments/applications.

Comment: Changed to "  print(paste(as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d", origin = "1970-01-01"),length(p)))" and of course changed origin in associated url call as well -- seems to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using dates in `loop` is not a good idea. Thus I made the following modifications:

```
  for (date in seq_along(dates)) {
    di = dates[date]
    url = paste0("http://nationalbank.kz/?docid=105&cmomdate=",
                 as.Date(di, format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                 "&switch=english")
```

Also, @Soren mentioned checking if `length(p) == 14`. This really helped. But checking `p` length is less crucial as the page may not contain the table at all. Instead of checking `length(p)` I decided to check `nrow(dt) == 14`. As in if the table has exactly 14 rows, then store the data to the list `ML`.

Happy to see any more robust solutions.